# Como debería de aplicar esta función de ruido en mi archivo pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hola buenas tengo que hacer una función para añadir ruido a todos los datos de un dataframe y mostrar la tabla resultante.

Para el resto de atributos utilizaremos ruido aditivo no correlacionado, tal y como se describe en los materiales.

Por eso utilizaremos una distribución normal (,2) con =0 , y como varianza tomaremos 2=2 donde 2 es la varianza de la variable que queremos proteger.

Desarrolle una función noise_add_normal(df, p) que recibe como parámetro df, DataFrame a anonimizar y el parámetro p, y devuelve una copia del DataFrame protegido, aplicando ruido a cada atributo.

Por último, obtenga una versión protegida en la variable df1_noise_1 utilizando =0.1 .

Algunas consideraciones:

cada atributo (variable o columna) tendrá una distribución de ruido independiente.
la función no puede modificar el DataFrame original, debe devolver un nuevo DataFrame.
tenga cuidado a la hora de pasar la varianza a la distribución normal de la librería numpy, fíjese que espera recibir la desviación estándar (no la varianza).
el resultado después de aplicar ruido NO debe estar redondeado a un decimal (como sí lo estaban los valores originales), ni debe aplicarse ninguna corrección.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("data/students1.csv")
del(df1['name'])

def noise_add_normal(df: pd.DataFrame, p: float) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df + np.random.normal(0, df.std() * np.sqrt(p), df.size)
    
p = 0.1
df1_noise_1 = noise_add_normal(df1, p)

df1_noise_1
```

No entiendo el error que me sale "ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape". Como debería aplicar la formula?

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

El error que te aparece se debe a que la operación de suma que intentas realizar entre el dataframe df y el array generado por np.random.normal no se puede realizar porque tienen diferentes formas (o shapes, en términos de numpy).

La forma de un array o dataframe indica su tamaño en cada dimensión, y en este caso, el array generado por np.random.normal no tiene la misma forma que el dataframe df, por lo que no se pueden sumar directamente.

Para solucionar este problema, puedes hacer que el array generado por np.random.normal tenga la misma forma que el dataframe df utilizando la función np.resize. La función np.resize permite cambiar la forma de un array para que tenga la misma forma que otro array.

Por ejemplo, podrías modificar tu código de la siguiente manera para que la función noise_add_normal funcione correctamente:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

def noise_add_normal(df: pd.DataFrame, p: float) -> pd.DataFrame:
    noise = np.random.normal(0, df.std() * np.sqrt(p), df.size)
    noise = np.resize(noise, df.shape)
    return df + noise

p = 0.1
df1_noise_1 = noise_add_normal(df1, p)

df1_noise_1
```

En este caso, se genera un array con el mismo tamaño que el dataframe df, se cambia la forma del array para que tenga la misma forma que el dataframe df, y luego se suma el array al dataframe para obtener el resultado final.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema.

**Editado: usuario agrega mayor descripción**

La función noise_add_normal() podría tener la siguiente estructura:

```
import numpy as np

def noise_add_normal(df, p):
  # se crea una copia del DataFrame original
  df_noise = df.copy()
  
  # se itera sobre cada columna del DataFrame
  for col in df_noise.columns:
    # se calcula la varianza de cada columna
    var = df_noise[col].var()

    # se aplica ruido a cada columna utilizando una distribución normal
    # con media 0 y varianza p * var
    df_noise[col] = df_noise[col] + np.random.normal(0, p * var, df_noise[col].shape)

  # se retorna el DataFrame protegido con ruido
  return df_noise
```

Para obtener una versión protegida del DataFrame original con un valor de  = 0.1, se podría utilizar la función de la siguiente manera:

```
# se utiliza la función noise_add_normal() para proteger el DataFrame original
df1_noise_1 = noise_add_normal(df1, 0.1)

# se muestra el DataFrame protegido
print(df1_noise_1)
```

Comment: Lo primero, muchas gracias Cristian por tu comentario, pero sigo teniendo el mismo error, en este caso en la línea 6 donde se define la operación que se debe hacer

Comment: Primero, asegúrate de haber importado numpy y pandas correctamente, y que has definido df1 como un DataFrame antes de llamar la función noise_add_normal.

Luego, intenta imprimir el resultado de noise_add_normal(df1, p) para ver qué es. Esto te ayudará a determinar si la función está funcionando correctamente y si el error está ocurriendo más adelante en el código.

Si aún tienes problemas, puedes proporcionar más información sobre el error que estás viendo

Comment: Buenas Cristian he revisado lo que has dicho y el error persiste,                                File mtrand.pyx:1507, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.normal()

File _common.pyx:562, in numpy.random._common.cont()

File _common.pyx:479, in numpy.random._common.cont_broadcast_2()

File __init__.pxd:742, in numpy.PyArray_MultiIterNew3()

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: Prueba cambiar la función de la linea 6 por noise = np.reshape(noise, df.shape) y me comentas

Comment: Si cambio la línea de sitio sale el siguiente error                                                                  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'noise' referenced before assignment

Comment: Podrías agregar más código a tu pregunta?, para poder entender mejor el problema

Comment: He puesto todo el código hasta llegar a esa parte, también he puesto en enunciado del ejercicio entero